# Blender 3.3 Character Fbx Export - Error Uploading to Mixamo

Tags: rigging, .fbx, mixamo

Hello im using blender and Mixamo for character rigging and animation almost 2 years. But with last blender update's (3.3 - 3.3.1) Mixamo can't recognise models and rigged characters exported from blender. Not just solid meshes for Mixamo auto rig also previously rigged with mixamo characters don't recognise from mixamo.

macOS monterey 12.5 - Blender 3.3 - 3.3.1 Apple Silicon

[image: Those are my mesh, rigged character and export settings.]

[image: export settings]
[image: Character Mesh]
[image: Mixamo Error for both]

Comment: I don't think your question is blender related. it's a problem in mixamo.

Comment: its perfectly works with blender 3.2 or earlier versions. but not 3.3

Comment: maybe try to ask Mixamo customer support why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any solution? Obj export works fine but not enough for me. When import fbx in 3ds max and again export as a fbx, mixamo is accepting that. Something wrong with Blender 3.3 fbx export, I couldnt figure it out.